# How do I upload my blob to my s3 bucket via lamda and api gateway?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload some data that I have obtained via my web form:

```
   <form class="container" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" name="formS3ObjManager" id="formS3ObjManagerId">

    <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Confirm your age" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Confirm your first name" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="file" name="file" id="file1" required />
        <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" required />
    </form>
```

They way in which I am doing it is via AWS lamda and apigateway.

I can easily upload my input files and the next thing I need to build into this web app is the ability to upload the form data as a text file to sit inside the s3 bucket alongside the accompanying files.

After googling around I have come up with the following to accomplish this:

```
        function uploadFile(s3Data, url) {

        var formData = new FormData();
    /*
    All the PreSigned URL fields to FormData as required by Amazon S3
    */
    for (key in s3Data.fields) {
        formData.append(key, s3Data.fields[key]);
    };
    /*
    Attach the file to be uploaded to FormData
    */
    formData.append('file', $('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0]);
    /**/
    const firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    const age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    lines = 'firstname:'+firstname +'      '+'age:'+ age

    let blob2 = new Blob([lines], { type: "text/plain"  });
            $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                    $('#status').html('<b> Uploading -> ' + (Math.round(percentComplete * 100)) + '% - do not close the browser window</b>');
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
            if (request.status === 200 || request.status === 204) {
                $("#urlTextId").html("Status: Uploaded Successfully.<br /> Object Key: " + s3Data.fields.key);
                $("#SignedUrlId").html("");
                console.log("Status:" + request.status);
                $("#div-obj-holderId").show();
            } else {
                $("#urlTextId").html("Br!! Unable to upload Object. Try again!! <br />Status:" + request.status);
            }
        },
    });
```

I don't know how to convert the blob (named as blob2 here) to a textfile i.e. example.txt which consists of the form data (age and firstname). I also don't know how to upload it via ajax post request.

Can I get some suggestions/solutions please?

Comment: here: var file = new File([blob], "filename"); reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831781/uploading-blob-file-to-amazon-s3

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. There are no errors that occur but there doesn't seem to be a text file in the s3

Comment: whats the s3 url that you are using

Comment: is the success block executed. add a `console.log()`  to the success block

Comment: where is your api gateway and lambda code. are you using api gateway and lambda to upload. or are you trying to upload directly to s3 from html

Comment: @arunk The console.log prints "undefined"
I am also uploading via api gateway --> Lamda -->s3.
I am able to successfully upload multiple files. Just not this blob

Comment: is the same code trying to upload a file and a blob as a file at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can add the blob to the FormData as below.

```
let blob2 = new Blob([lines], { type: "text/plain"  });
formData.append("blob",blob2, 'example.txt');
```

If you are using s3 presigned url, you cannot upload in two files in the same request.

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)